# Does crouching make it harder for Roadhog's hook to hit you?

Tags: overwatch

So, there have been quite a few questions revolving around Roadhog recently. To save space on the title, the real question is:

Can heroes crouch to avoid Roadhog's hook?

Considering a perfectly accurate Roadhog, **can I dodge the hook without moving?** I have seen in a gfycat posted on Reddit that a Zenyatta crouched under the hook, saving himself from a face full of Rolin's man meat. Is this possible for the whole cast, or was it a fluke thing?

Edit: [Here's the GFY](https://gfycat.com/CriminalDampGermanwirehairedpointer)

Comment: I think the title of this question is misleading. How to avoid getting hooked is not the same as does crouching affect hook hitbox. I came into this question to downvote it, but I'm not because the actual question is stated better than the title. Just my thoughts.

Comment: @ChaseC If you've got a better suggestion for a title, go for it!

Comment: In the gif it looks like the hook passes to Zenyatta's right rather than over his head. It would've been much more beneficial to see that from Roadhog's point of view to really make a call on that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**No.**

Crouching will not help you a tiny bit, as the hit-box of the hook is enormously huge, much bigger than what Hanzo's is, for example compared to the model (as he's complained to have really big hitbox arrows).

Well not that much to actually care about. It does reduce the hitbox, but if the Roadhog against you is anything above 250 raiting, then he'll be aiming at least somewhat at your height, and as show bellow this wont save you.

Check this [video](https://youtu.be/rQ-sip4-CFw?t=242) at 4:00 for more details. Basically the hook is actually twice as large as the model shows. Soldier is definitely crouching and the shooter is aiming quite high, yet he got hooked.

The hook and the animation have a weird mechanic, and that's why many people were dragged trough walls and across the map before people got teleported to the point where they got hooked. When you hit the button to hook someone, and the croshair is on the target, this doesn't mean that you'll hook them. Nor is the case when the hook starts to fly towards the target. The hit scan actually triggers about half way into the throwing animation. Roadhog kind of points to his target, while throwing, this is the exact moment when he'll hit-scan and hook you. [And that's what I'm talking about.](https://youtu.be/MiC9kRcRz3k?t=62) (1 minute into the video)

Comment: This is not entirely accurate... crouching does help, minimally, since the hitbox shrinks and gives Roadhog a smaller target. However, the hook hitbox is pretty big, so often it looks like it doesn't help. Also I don't think the hook is a hitscan, otherwise it would be impossible to dodge as Tracer.

Comment: @MageXy Technically yes, but you have to be aiming pretty high for this tiny difference to matter. Check the video at the 4th minute onward.

Comment: Wait, you're saying the hook automatically hits based on where it is located halfway through it's animation? This can't be true.

Comment: @ChaseC It is and I'll try to find the video where they discovered it.

Comment: @ChaseC https://youtu.be/MiC9kRcRz3k?t=62

Comment: Huh...hard to argue with that kind of evidence really. No wonder hooking feels kind of...off sometimes.

Comment: @ChaseC and as a non roadhog player - so frustrating to play against, as you were 10000% sure u dodged it...

Comment: Sorry. But this is not what you say it is. Roadhog's hook have a delay on the shift press. Roadhog's hook doesn't have a perma hitbox either (Explaining the hook going through the target). It's not a hitscan, Hitscan would imply that the hook would instantly acquire a target (even after the delay) which isn't the case since it still have a travel time.

Comment: The phenomenon that you get grabbed through a wall is called "acquisition time". Roadhog's hook has landed on you but has not reeled you in yet leaving a little bit of time for you to move behind a wall. (a bit due to server lag and the prediction system that Blizzard has implemented)

Comment: @Karlyr if the hook has landed on you, you're stunned. The ""acquisition time"" is the time between what I'm talking about in my last paragraph (middle of roadhog's animation) and the time he starts hooking.

Comment: You are not -instantly- stunned. There's a delay. Any Roadhog player will say you that. you see the target hooked, the hook travels with the target and then the character is reeled in. This is why some characters were hooked along the side of the wall after the hook. I say were because the last patch to roadhog's hook made it a **lot** less frequent.

Answer (score 2):

It depends on where Roadhog actually throw his hook. I personnally have the tendancy to shoot higher than lower because more people jump than crouch in a fray.

So if I play Roadhog and the enemy crouches, there's a possibility that my hook misses. (Because your hitbox becomes less high).

In the case of the video linked, I don't even think the crouch really helped Zenyatta there. The hook seems like it was missed to the right of Zenyatta in the first place. We would have to see Roadhog's perspective to completly tell.

In short, yes crouching does help **but so little that it probably won't matter.** You have a lot more chances to just juke him by rapidly switching directions than trying to crouch.

Comment: I agree, the hook clearly missed the Zenyatta because it was to his right, the fact that he crouched did nothing.

Answer (score 1):

A perfectly accurate Roadhog would be aiming at the primary mass of the target. Crouching does not move the hero's hitbox, only shrinks it a bit. As a result, in most cases, the Roadhog will still hook whoever was crouching. The exception is if the Roadhog aimed more upwards, meaning that the hook's hitbox will pass over the crouching target and miss.

Roadhog's hook has a reputation for being very wonky, so it's possible that the Roadhog missed his hook to begin with, or it could be one of those weird cases where it looks like it should have hit but didn't. Based on the gif you supplied, it looks like the Roadhog aimed too far to his right - the crouching had nothing to do with the the dodge.

Comment: Is this the case with every character, even Ana, who crouches quite low?

Comment: Yes. Roadhog's hook is entirely dependent on hitboxes. Crouching reduces the size of the hero's hitbox, and thus makes it more likely for the Roadhog to miss - but a good Roadhog wouldn't be aiming his hook at people's head to begin with.

Comment: Okay. I added a link to the GFY in the original post, now that I look at it more it just looks like Roadhog mis-judged Zen's placement, and the Zen happened to crouch too.

Comment: @Kaizerwolf He didn't get hooked not because he ducked, but because ROadhog missed. SLow the video down to 0.125 speed and have a look. The rope was already trough zen's face when he ducked. I'll explain how the hook works in my answer bellow.